# Connecting to Oracle DB using Bottle in Python

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, connection, bottle, cx-oracle

Dears,
I am making simple web page using Bottle library in Python. And started struggling when i want to connect to Oracle DB and extract data from table for visualization. I see that Bottle has only Sqlite.db connections. Is it possible to connect to Oracle db with integrated Bottle library functionality? Or should i call cx_Oracle each time when a web page link is pressed to get data from database?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you? https://github.com/bormotov/bottle-oracle. I haven't used it myself but the code in it is simple enough you can develop your own if need be! Hope that helps, anyway.